# Strange memory content display in Visual Studio debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, hook, visual-studio-debugging

I am writing some multi-thread C program. I tried to modify the few instructions at the beginning of a function's body to redirect the execution to somewhere else.

But I noticed that when debugging within Visual Studio 2015, some memory location seems to be unchangeable as displayed in the `Memory` window.

For example:

In below picture, a function `ApSignalMceToOs()` begins at `0x7FFBBEE51360`. I have unprotected the memory range `0x7FFBBEE51360` to `0x7FFBBEE5136E` to modify it.

Line 305 to 312 modify the address range `0x7FFBBEE51360` ~ `0x7FFBBEE5136E`.

Everything is fine until `0x7FFBBEE51369`. At line 311, the `(uint32_t(((uintptr_t)dst) >> 32` is `0x00007ffb`.
After line 311 is executed, I was expecting the memory range in `0x7FFBBEE51369` ~ `0x7FFBBEE5136C` will be filled as `fb 7f 00 00`. But as shown below, Visual Studio says it is `48 7f 00 00`, where the `48` is the old value.

[image]

Then I went to check the disassembly code of the function `ApSignalMceToOs()`. And not surprisingly, the instruction at `00007FFBBF171365` is `mov dword ptr [rsp+4], 7F48h`, which **should** be `7FFB`. As shown below in the **red** box below.

[image]

So until this point, Visual Studio 2015 is telling me that my modification **would** fail.

But as the yellow arrow in **above** picture shows, after the `mov dword ptr [rsp+4], 7F48h` is executed, I checked the content in the stack area. **Surprisingly** it is indeed `7f fb` got moved onto the stack (shown in the **green** box in **above** picture).

And after the `ret` instruction is executed, the `RIP` register does change to `00007FFBBEEAD940`, which is no surprise. See below:

[image]

And in another function, the same location is being read. Shown as below:

[image]
The `code[len]` or `byte ptr [rax]` is the memory location holding `48` or `fb`. But it reads `0xcc`, which is neither `0x48` nor `0xfb`.

Visual Studio disassembly code is decoded from the memory content. So the memory content or **how VS2015 read/refresh it** is the key point.

Based on above observation, I came to 2 conclusions with VS 2015 debug mode:

- Some memory content is not correctly shown (or refreshed in GUI).
- Some memory read operation doesn't work correctly.

**But the program runs smoothly when not debugging.**

Does anyone know why this is happening?

### ADD 1 - 5:08 PM 10/14/2019

Thanks to @MichaelBurr. I guess I can explain it now.

The root cause is I added a breakpoint at `0x00007FFB...369` **at the disassembly code level, not the C source level.**

[image]

When I did this, the VS Debugger **did** add a `0xCC` instruction at the location `0x00007FFB...369`. But it seems **Visual Studio 2015 goes to great lengths to hide this fact**. Below is the show of the memory content with the breakpoint at `0x00007FFB...369`, we can see `0x00007FFB...369` still holds the old value `0x48`.

[image]

But after I manually copied the memory from `0x00007FFB...360` to `0x00007FFB...36e` to somewhere else. The `0xCC` instruction at the offset `0x9` is **unveiled**. See below:

[image]

When I modify the content at `0x00007FFB...369`, Visual Studio seemed to be alerted and it just restored the content to the old preserved one, i.e. `0x48`. Not my newly written one.

**But I think this very restoration doesn't make any sense. The restoration of the preserved byte content shouldn't be triggered at this moment in any way. A more reasonable action is to update the breakpoint's location a little bit and insert the 0xCC instruction to a new location. Because the newly modified code may change the "instruction boundary". This way, the debug experience of the self-modifying code can be best preserved. But this will require the Visual Studio to disassemble the new code in the nearby. And the new instruction content could be invalid if the programmer made a mistake.**

Comment: I hope someone from the Microsoft can read my post and see if it is possible to improve Visual Studio a little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are essentially fighting with the debugger's breakpoint/single step handling. Breakpoints are often implemented with the `int 3` instruction which has the encoding `0xCC`. When the debugger sets the `0xCC` for the breakpoint it has to save the original value, then replace it when the debugger has stopped program execution.

In a normal situation (code that isn't self-modified) this makes things appear as you expect when examining the code memory region. However if your program modifies the memory that is being managed by the debugger you can get confusing results since the debugger will restore the value it had saved when it set the breakpoint (overwriting your modification).

Comment: I added some of my analysis to my post. Could you have a look? Thanks.